# how to generate and run dynamic sql in vertica

Tags: vertica

I am planning to maintain logic for a derived field in a look up table and thinking of running dynamic  sql statements real time.

for example , if field company_type is derived based on the following logic

`case when substr(company_code,1,3)='XYZ' then substr(comapny_code,4,6)
     when substr(company_code,1,3)='ABC' then substr(company_code,7,9)
     else substr(company_code,1,3) end;`

to avoid code changes whenever a new case is provided by business i want to maintain the logic in a look up table like following

```
order          src_filed                               src_value 
--------------------------------------------------------------
  1     substr(company_code,1,3)='XYZ'          substr(4,6)
  2     substr(company_code,1,3)='ABC'          substr(7,9)
  3                                             substr(1,3)
```

now based on the data in look up table , i want to be able to generate case statement dynamically and to be able to run the case statemnent. Note that i need to run that dynamic sql as part of another sql where i query source tables that has source fields.

Answer (score 1):

This feature doesn't exist yet in Vertica. Hopefully in a future version. Easiest method is to write a script to execute the sql via vsql or jdbc.